With Livewire 3, how can I use multiple inputs with the same wire:model?
I have a form that has the feature to create multiple input fields (works with AlpineJS). In the backend, i have the attribute "form.cooked_weight" thar references the inputs fields. When I try to get the values, it does not work.
My RecipeForm.php file:
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Forms;

use Livewire\Attributes\Validate;
use Livewire\Form;

class RecipeForm extends Form
{
    #[Validate(['cooked_weight.*' => ['required','numeric', 'min:0']])]
    public $cooked_weight;

}

My store.blade.php file (simplified):
<?php

use Livewire\Attributes\Layout;
use Livewire\Volt\Component;
use App\Livewire\Forms\RecipeForm;
use App\Models\Recipe;


new #[Layout('layouts.app')] class extends Component {
    public RecipeForm $form;
    
}
?>
<div>
    <x-input-label for="cooked_weight[]" value="* Peso de la receta cocida" />
    <div class='flex flex-row items-center space-x-3'>
        <x-text-input wire:model.live='form.cooked_weight[]' id="cooked_weight" name="cooked_weight" type="number" step="0.01" value="0" required />
        <x-text-input wire:model.live='form.cooked_weight[]' id="cooked_weight" name="cooked_weight" type="number" step="0.01" value="0" required />
    </div>
    <x-input-error class="mt-2" :messages="$errors->get('form.cooked_weight')" />
</div>

I expected to get an error message when the input does not match with the validation rule, but I got nothing.

Have you tried looping through them and adding the index/key to each element? Something like:
foreach($cooked_weight as $index => $weight) <div> <input type="text" wire:model="cooked_weight.{{ $index }}"> </div> @endforeach

@vkal yes, I tried without success, the validation does not work with that way.

name="cooked_weight[]"
